# java8 make asynhronous I/O

Tags: java, stream, copy

Can somebody help me. I am new in Java and i want to copy file from one directory to another with CompletableFuture or ListenableFuture, but i dont know how to do this.

```
   public void trackFiles(File source) {
        if (source.exists()) {
            File[] files = source.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    trackFiles(file);
                } else {
                    allFile.add(file);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No such files!");
        }
    }

    public void copyAllFilesRecursive(File source, File destination, CopyOption... options) {
        if (source.isDirectory()) {
            if (!destination.exists()) {
                destination.mkdirs();

            }
        }
        File[] contents = source.listFiles();

        if (contents != null) {
            ArrayList<File> listContents = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(contents));
            listContents.forEach(file -> {
                File newFile = new File(destination.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + file.getName());
                if (file.isDirectory() && file.exists()) {
                    copyAllFilesRecursive(file, newFile, options);
                } else {
                    try {
                        copyFiles(file, newFile, options);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(file + " exists");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync(java.lang.Runnable), or if you need to return a result: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync(java.util.function.Supplier)

Comment: This won't necessarily make the work any faster, but it will make it more complicated and error prone.

Comment: I want to make this more readabale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in trying to make this operation asynchronous.

If you want a more readable code, you should use NIO, e.g.

```
public static void copyTree(Path from, Path to, CopyOption... options) throws IOException {
    if(!Files.exists(to)) Files.createDirectories(to);

    Files.walkFileTree(from, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                                                                       throws IOException {
            return !dir.equals(from)? copy(dir): FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                                                                       throws IOException {
            return copy(file);
        }

        private FileVisitResult copy(Path file) throws IOException {
            Files.copy(file, to.resolve(from.relativize(file)), options);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}
```

This will copy the content of `from` to `to`, e.g. when copying `foo/bar` to `baz`, it will copy everything within `foo\bar` to `baz`. If instead, you want the `from` directory copied, e.g. `baz\bar` created and everything within `foo\bar` copied to `baz\bar`, use

```
public static void copyTree(Path from, Path to, CopyOption... options) throws IOException {
    from = from.toAbsolutePath();
    Path base = from.getParent();
    if(!Files.exists(to)) Files.createDirectories(to);

    Files.walkFileTree(from, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                                                                       throws IOException {
            return copy(dir);
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                                                                       throws IOException {
            return copy(file);
        }

        private FileVisitResult copy(Path file) throws IOException {
            Files.copy(file, to.resolve(base.relativize(file)), options);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}
```

If you really need the shown front-end method, it’s now as simple as

```
public static void copyAllFilesRecursive(File source, File destination,
                                         CopyOption... options)        throws IOException {
    copyTree(source.toPath(), destination.toPath());
}
```

though it is very strange to combine the NIO `CopyOption` type with the legacy IO `File` type in one method…

Comment: Thank you, nice view. Now is more better, but I hope to make this with guava